Movies Tracker apps development
Assalamu Alaykum Warahmatu Lah Ta'ala wa barakatuhu.
I work as a freelancer in app development, and I want to know the ruling on creating an app for movies that allows users to see new movies from around the world. For example, users can see images, descriptions, and some trailers of the movies, but they cannot watch the movies in this app, only summaries. The app uses a library that contains all the movies(https://www.themoviedb.org/), and by using this library, I bring all the movies to my app. I have copyright permission from the website that provides this library to use those movies in my apps.
However, as I mentioned, users cannot watch movies except trailers and those trailers are silent by default. Also, I apply a blurry filter to the images so they are not displayed clearly unless the user chooses to disable this feature from the app settings. Additionally, I'm using a filter that removes any movie that may contain inappropriate images or similar content about 95%.
So, what is the Islamic religious ruling on creating an app that contains movie summaries?

Wa 3laykum As Salaam Wa Rahmathullaahi Wa Barakaathahu, I wanted to ask who mentioned watching movies is haraam. Because watching movies is not haraam inherently. It is what you are watching and listening to in it become haram. So I could be watching a documentary film on animals. Technically its a movie/film but would not be haraam to watch. The question is what movies are you making, are they 3d movies / animated or what type?

Thank you Ahmed for your reply. I want to clarify I'm not making movies I'm developing apps that allow users to see a bunch of movies from around the world by using an API(application programming interface) called (https://www.themoviedb.org/). I'm publishing those apps in Play & App Store. The apps as I mentioned contain just images, descriptions, and some trailers of the movies the app kind called Movies Tracker or Movies Guide here is an example of those apps: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tving-kdramas-cinemax/id6480036020. what is the ruling on developing and programming those apps?
